# jquery on click event not registered within a Coffeescript class

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

```
class Bundler
  constructor: ->
    @bing()

  bing: ->
    $(document).on "click", "#me", (event) ->
      console.log 'click registered'

$ ->
  new Bundler
```

Above code is expected to output "click registered", but it is never called. Not sure what's the issue with this?

Comment: `bind;` doesn't call the function.  You need to do `bind();`.

Comment: Maybe showing us the original CoffeeScript would be helpful. That's what you have to fix, right?

Comment: Executive Summary: The parentheses are required when calling a function in CoffeeScript when that function isn't being passed any arguments. You need to say `constructor: -> bind()` in your CoffeeScript `class Bundler` rather than just `constructor: -> bind`.

Comment: I include the original CoffeeScript. Even including the parentheses still not works.